# C "undefined reference to" error while compiling COSEG from RepeatMasker developers

Tags: c, ubuntu, makefile

I'm trying to compile COSEG, a program from the RepeatMasker developers (link: http://www.repeatmasker.org/COSEGDownload.html) on Xubuntu.

After unpacking the distribution I enter the directory and try to run `make` in my terminal but I get many "undefined reference to" errors:

```
massimiliano@compaq2:~/Programs/coseg$ make
cc -O4 -lm version.o coseg.o -o coseg 
coseg.o: In function `compute_siegel_tri_pvalue.part.0':
coseg.c:(.text+0xa1): undefined reference to `log'
coseg.c:(.text+0xae): undefined reference to `exp'
coseg.c:(.text+0x47b): undefined reference to `log'
coseg.c:(.text+0x4c2): undefined reference to `exp'
coseg.c:(.text+0x4d7): undefined reference to `log'
coseg.c:(.text+0x683): undefined reference to `log'
coseg.c:(.text+0x6d7): undefined reference to `exp'
coseg.c:(.text+0x6e4): undefined reference to `log'
coseg.c:(.text+0x70f): undefined reference to `sqrt'
coseg.c:(.text+0x72d): undefined reference to `sqrt'
coseg.c:(.text+0x757): undefined reference to `sqrt'
coseg.o: In function `compute_siegel_pvalue.part.1':
coseg.c:(.text+0x7da): undefined reference to `log'
coseg.c:(.text+0x7e7): undefined reference to `exp'
coseg.c:(.text+0x97f): undefined reference to `exp'
coseg.c:(.text+0x98c): undefined reference to `log'
coseg.c:(.text+0x9ff): undefined reference to `log'
coseg.c:(.text+0xad7): undefined reference to `exp'
coseg.c:(.text+0xae4): undefined reference to `log'
coseg.c:(.text+0xb4d): undefined reference to `log'
coseg.c:(.text+0xbe7): undefined reference to `sqrt'
coseg.c:(.text+0xc05): undefined reference to `sqrt'
coseg.o: In function `compute_pvalue.part.2':
coseg.c:(.text+0xd3b): undefined reference to `log'
coseg.c:(.text+0xd4c): undefined reference to `log'
coseg.c:(.text+0xe24): undefined reference to `exp'
coseg.c:(.text+0xe86): undefined reference to `log'
coseg.c:(.text+0xe97): undefined reference to `log'
coseg.o: In function `compute_tri_pvalue.part.3':
coseg.c:(.text+0x10e4): undefined reference to `exp'
coseg.o: In function `inverseNormalCDF':
coseg.c:(.text+0x141e): undefined reference to `log'
coseg.c:(.text+0x150f): undefined reference to `sqrt'
coseg.o: In function `allocate_memory':
coseg.c:(.text+0x15de): undefined reference to `log'
coseg.c:(.text+0x166c): undefined reference to `log'
coseg.c:(.text+0x16cc): undefined reference to `log'
coseg.o: In function `compute_tri_pvalue':
coseg.c:(.text+0x303a): undefined reference to `log'
coseg.c:(.text+0x3047): undefined reference to `exp'
coseg.o: In function `compute_pvalue':
coseg.c:(.text+0x31e6): undefined reference to `log'
coseg.c:(.text+0x31f3): undefined reference to `exp'
coseg.o: In function `compute_score':
coseg.c:(.text+0x32cd): undefined reference to `log'
coseg.c:(.text+0x32da): undefined reference to `exp'
coseg.o: In function `compute_tri_score':
coseg.c:(.text+0x3386): undefined reference to `log'
coseg.c:(.text+0x3393): undefined reference to `exp'
coseg.o: In function `compute_tri_bestmut':
coseg.c:(.text+0x628c): undefined reference to `log'
coseg.c:(.text+0x629b): undefined reference to `exp'
coseg.o: In function `split_pvaluelocal':
coseg.c:(.text+0x6e55): undefined reference to `log'
coseg.c:(.text+0x734d): undefined reference to `log'
coseg.c:(.text+0x735a): undefined reference to `exp'
coseg.o: In function `compute_bestmut':
coseg.c:(.text+0x7ff3): undefined reference to `log'
coseg.c:(.text+0x8000): undefined reference to `exp'
coseg.o: In function `union_tri_pvalue':
coseg.c:(.text+0x91fd): undefined reference to `log'
coseg.c:(.text+0x920a): undefined reference to `exp'
coseg.c:(.text+0x934e): undefined reference to `log'
coseg.c:(.text+0x935b): undefined reference to `exp'
coseg.o: In function `union_pvalue':
coseg.c:(.text+0x9e1c): undefined reference to `log'
coseg.c:(.text+0x9e29): undefined reference to `exp'
coseg.o: In function `build_MST':
coseg.c:(.text+0xb232): undefined reference to `exp'
coseg.o: In function `compute_sigma':
coseg.c:(.text+0xb7d4): undefined reference to `log'
coseg.c:(.text+0xb7e1): undefined reference to `exp'
coseg.o: In function `compute_bestmut1':
coseg.c:(.text+0xbb27): undefined reference to `log'
coseg.c:(.text+0xbb34): undefined reference to `exp'
coseg.o: In function `build_new_subfamily2':
coseg.c:(.text+0xd265): undefined reference to `exp'
coseg.c:(.text+0xd2a6): undefined reference to `log'
coseg.c:(.text+0xd4ad): undefined reference to `exp'
coseg.c:(.text+0xd4ee): undefined reference to `log'
coseg.o: In function `sigmage_to_logpvalue':
coseg.c:(.text+0xd8a8): undefined reference to `exp'
coseg.c:(.text+0xd8ec): undefined reference to `log'
coseg.o: In function `build_new_singlemut_subfamily':
coseg.c:(.text+0xdb4d): undefined reference to `exp'
coseg.c:(.text+0xdb8e): undefined reference to `log'
coseg.c:(.text+0xdd7d): undefined reference to `exp'
coseg.c:(.text+0xddbe): undefined reference to `log'
coseg.o: In function `build_singlemut_MST':
coseg.c:(.text+0xe608): undefined reference to `log'
coseg.c:(.text+0xe615): undefined reference to `exp'
coseg.c:(.text+0xe8ce): undefined reference to `log'
coseg.c:(.text+0xe8db): undefined reference to `exp'
coseg.o: In function `build_MST2':
coseg.c:(.text+0xf38f): undefined reference to `exp'
coseg.c:(.text+0xf5d0): undefined reference to `exp'
coseg.c:(.text+0xf7c9): undefined reference to `exp'
coseg.c:(.text+0xf814): undefined reference to `log'
coseg.c:(.text+0xf85f): undefined reference to `exp'
coseg.c:(.text+0xfb3c): undefined reference to `exp'
coseg.c:(.text+0xfb97): undefined reference to `log'
coseg.c:(.text+0xfbf6): undefined reference to `exp'
coseg.c:(.text+0xfcd8): undefined reference to `sqrt'
coseg.c:(.text+0xfd51): undefined reference to `sqrt'
coseg.o: In function `print_subfamilies':
coseg.c:(.text+0xffe0): undefined reference to `exp'
coseg.c:(.text+0x10024): undefined reference to `log'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [coseg] Error 1
```

Searching the internet I have found that probably it is a 'linking' problem and I have to add/modify some lines of code in the makefile but this kind of stuffs are very new to me and I am not a programmer, so I feel a bit confused.

Do you have some tips or suggestions to help me to solve this problem, please?

Thank you very much for your time!

Massimiliano.

**Update:**
Trying to compile the previous version of the program, gives me an additional warning:

```
echo "char const* Version = \"0.2.1\";" > version.c
cc -O4 -lm    -c -o version.o version.c
cc -O4 -lm    -c -o coseg.o coseg.c
coseg.c: In function ‘inverseNormalCDF’:
coseg.c:973:5: warning: format ‘%lf’ expects a matching ‘double’ argument [-Wformat]
```

**Update - Makefile:**
This is the Makefile unpacked with the distribution:

```
##
## Makefile for coseg project
##
VERSION=0.2.2
INSTALLDIR=/usr/local/coseg-${VERSION}

## Basic
CC = cc -O4 -lm
## A nice memory leak checker:
#CC = bgcc -O4 -fbounds-checking -lm

all: coseg 

version.c: Makefile
    echo "char const* Version = \"$(VERSION)\";" > version.c

coseg: version.o coseg.o
    ${CC} version.o coseg.o -o coseg 

beautify:
    indent -bap -cdb -bl -bli0 -npcs -nut -lp coseg.c

install: coseg
    -mkdir ${INSTALLDIR}
    cp coseg ${INSTALLDIR}
    cp README ${INSTALLDIR}
    cp preprocessAlignments.pl ${INSTALLDIR}
    cp postprocess.pl ${INSTALLDIR}
    cp runcoseg.pl ${INSTALLDIR}
    cp extractSubSeqs.pl ${INSTALLDIR}
    cp refineConsSeqs.pl ${INSTALLDIR}
    cp ALU.cons ${INSTALLDIR}
    cp ALU.ins ${INSTALLDIR}
    cp ALU.seqs ${INSTALLDIR}
    cp LINE1 ${INSTALLDIR}


dist:
    -mkdir dist
    -mkdir dist/coseg
    cp ALU.cons dist/coseg
    cp ALU.ins dist/coseg
    cp ALU.seqs dist/coseg
    cp LINE1 dist/coseg
    cp Makefile dist/coseg
    cp README dist/coseg
    cp coseg.c dist/coseg
    cp coseg.h dist/coseg
    cp postprocess.pl dist/coseg
    cp preprocessAlignments.pl dist/coseg
    cp runcoseg.pl dist/coseg
    cp extractSubSeqs.pl dist/coseg
    cp refineConsSeqs.pl dist/coseg
    (cd dist; tar zcvf coseg-$(VERSION).tar.gz coseg)

clean:
    -rm *.o
    -rm coseg
    -rm version.c
    -rm ALU.seqs.subfamilies.seq
    -rm ALU.seqs.assign
    -rm ALU.seqs.log
    -rm ALU.seqs.subfamilies
    -rm ALU.seqs.tree.viz


ALU.seqs.subfamilies.seq: coseg
    ./runcoseg.pl -d -filePrefix ALU

t/kothi.seqs.subfamilies.seq: coseg
    ./runcoseg.pl -u1 -t -m 5 -filePrefix t/kothi

test: ALU.seqs.subfamilies.seq t/kothi.seqs.subfamilies.seq
    diff ALU.seqs.subfamilies.seq t
    diff t/kothi.seqs.subfamilies.seq t/kothi-baseline
```

Comment: Did you `./configure`? it? `make clean`?

Comment: Yes but I get these two errors: `bash: ./configure: No such file or directory` and `make: [clean] Error 1 (ignored)`. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Some linkers expect to have the libraries specified _after_ the object files which use symbols from it. Can you try to link with `cc -O4 version.o coseg.o -lm -o coseg`?

Comment: I've never seen C code until now, but I think I have to put your code in the makefile. So in the makefile I have:

`CC = cc -O4 -lm` and

`coseg: version.o coseg.o
 ${CC} version.o coseg.o -o coseg`

If I put your code substituting CC running something like this:

`CC = cc -O4 version.o coseg.o -lm -o coseg` and

`coseg: version.o coseg.o
 ${CC} `

I get this error `cc: warning: version.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
cc: warning: coseg.o: linker input file unused because linking not done`

Comment: @Revo Just try to execute it in the cli first and see if linking succeeds that way

Comment: Ok, if I try to run it in the cli the command works but the following `make` still get me the same initial errors. Thank you very much for our time.

Comment: @Revo Edit your question to include your (original) makefile please.

Comment: @Revo: change it to `CC = cc -O4` and `$(CC) version.o coseg.o -o coseg -lm`.

Comment: @Revo I have put a suggested fix for your makefile into the answer below.

Comment: I have downloaded the package from the link in the questions and it gets installed without any errors. The problem here is that the linker fails to find libm.so and hence complaints about log(), sqrt() etc functions used in coseg.c. 
You need to ensure that you have libm.so ( typically at /lib64/libm.so) on your machine and it is being used by the linker.

Could you print the output of 
`cc -m64 -Xlinker --verbose  2>/dev/null | grep SEARCH | sed 's/SEARCH_DIR("=\?\([^"]\+\)"); */\1\n/g'  | grep -vE '^$'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some linkers (including yours) need to have the libraries specified *after* the object files (or other libraries), which use symbols from it. This can even lead to the necessity to specify libraries multiply if cyclic dependencies are involved.

In your case `coseg.o` uses symbols from `libm`, so you would have to specify `-lm` after coseg.o in your command: `cc -O4 version.o coseg.o -lm -o coseg`

I suggest you change your `Makefile` to:

```
##
## Makefile for coseg project
##
VERSION=0.2.2
INSTALLDIR=/usr/local/coseg-${VERSION}

## Basic
CC = cc
CFLAGS = -O4
LDFLAGS = -lm
## A nice memory leak checker:
#CC = bgcc -O4 -fbounds-checking -lm

all: coseg 

version.c: Makefile
    echo "char const* Version = \"$(VERSION)\";" > version.c

coseg: version.o coseg.o
    ${CC} version.o coseg.o ${LDFLAGS} -o coseg 

... rest of makefile ...
```

That should fix your problem.

Comment: I have been able to compile without any change in the order, so no issues with the order here.

Comment: @Phalgun So if it works for you it has to work for everyone? ;) The OP has a linker where the order _is_ an issue, and that is not a very rare case.

Comment: Ok I think we are very near to solve it. Making this changing, it gives me a warning `echo "char const* Version = \"0.2.2\";" > version.c
cc -O4   -c -o version.o version.c
cc -O4   -c -o coseg.o coseg.c
coseg.c: In function ‘inverseNormalCDF’:
coseg.c:1288:5: warning: format ‘%lf’ expects a matching ‘double’ argument [-Wformat]
cc version.o coseg.o -lm -o coseg`
but now I have some new files in the coseg directory.
However thank you very much for the clear explanation of the issue :)

Comment: @Ctx Agreed it may work for others, but I would not prefer making a statement like 'need to have the libraries specified after the object files'; if it needs to, then it always should, but since that is not the case always, I would abstain from saying that.

Comment: @Revo this is a bug in the code. See the printf() in line 1288 in coseg.c?`. It has no argument for the `%lf`, try to change it to `printf("...", x);` to get rid of the warning.

Comment: @Phalgun Hm? I clearly wrote "Some linkers need to" to make clear that for others this may not be necessary. On the other hand, it doesn't hurt to be on the safe side, does it?

Comment: wow Ctx you are a magician, now it works very well. Thank you very much, your help was invaluable! :)

Comment: @revo you nailed it :)